# How to Implement Editable Popover on Bootstrap DataTable Column Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

How to Implement Editable Popover on Bootstrap DataTable Column Grid. As bootstrap popover do not support class based implementation.

I want something like below for my Data-table.

[image]

```
 $('#prodname1').editable({
    type: 'text',
    pk: 1,
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Enter Product Name'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do  like this classbased is now supported.

```
 <td> <a href="#" class="edit" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-original-title="Product Name"> Product One </a></td>
```

And the JS script

```
$('.edit').editable({
    type: 'text',
    title: 'Edit'
    });
```